# Substitute function of derivatives and its argument in xAct

Tags: xact

I am using xAct to do some tensor computation. Consider the following term

```
CD[-a][CD[a][\[Phi][]]]CD[-b][CD[b][\[Phi][]]]
```

which is latex is

$$
D_a D^a \phi\, D_b D^b \phi
$$

where $\phi$ is defined to be a field in xAct and $D_a$ are derivatives.

Now, the command I wrote is a function like

```
f[-x_][f[x_][g]]
```

I would like to substitute $D_a D^a \phi \rightarrow D_a D^a \phi^3$ that is,

```
f[-x_][f[x_][g]] >>> f[-x_][f[x_][g g g]]
```

How can I do this with Mathematica? I tried with

```
/. CD[-a_][CD[a_][_]] -> CD[-a_][CD[a_][\[Phi][] \[Phi][] \[Phi][]]]
```

but it does not work